# CFWheels - Validate two different forms using the same model

Tags: model-view-controller, coldfusion, railo, cfwheels

I'm new to wheels (and I'm sure I'll be posting here a lot) so bear with me.

I have two forms "register" and "login" under the controller of "user". So my URL's look like.

/user/register/
/user/login/

At the moment in my models folder I simply have user.cfc with validation for the "register" page inside the init method - this works just fine.

So essentially...my question is...regarding validation for my login form; do I have to always place validation into the init method or in a different one? If so, how do I do this? Each form of course has different fields...so I need to know some logic on detecting what form is currently in play.

Hope this makes sense. For reference, my user.cfc model currently looks like this:

```
<cfcomponent extends="Model" output="true">

    <cffunction name="init">

        <cfset validate( property='userName', method='validateAlphaNumeric') />
        <cfset validatesPresenceOf( properties='userName') />
        <cfset validatesUniquenessOf( properties='userName') />

        <cfset validatesFormatOf( property='userEmail', type='email', message="Email address is not in a valid format.") />
        <cfset validatesPresenceOf( properties='userEmail') />
        <cfset validatesUniquenessOf( properties='userEmail') />

        <cfset validatesPresenceOf( properties='userPassword') />
        <cfset validatesConfirmationOf( property='userPassword') />

        <cfset validatesLengthOf( property="userToken", allowBlank=true) />

    </cffunction>

    <cffunction name="validateAlphaNumeric" access="private">
        <cfif REFind("[^A-Za-z0-9]", this.userName, 1)>
            <cfset addError( property="userName", message="User name can only contain letters and numbers." ) />
        </cfif>
    </cffunction>

</cfcomponent>
```

Thanks,
Michael.

Comment: In your very first validation rule, you do not need `property='userName'`. The only thing it needs is the `method` argument.

Answer (score 1):

Michael,

You do need to put model validations in your init() method; Wheels requires that. However, I am not sure you would want or need to use model validation for the login page/call.

Unless I am missing something, you're not actually altering the model (i.e., creating a new or updating an existing user) when a user logs into a site. You are simply authenticating them (checking their username/password combo) against your DB values.

If it were me, I'd use client-side validation for login (fields are completed, etc.) and model validation for register.

HTH!
Craig

Comment: You're right Craig...I may not need validation for a login, but what if I want to create an edit page or some other form under "user"...it would use the same model...and that's where I get stuck. Hopefully, you know what I mean.

Comment: I think I do, Michael. In my wheels apps, I have a filter I use in my models to ensure that users are authenticated when they try to access restricted materials. The filter ("loginRequired") checks if a user is logged in and, if not, redirects them to my "login" route (set in config/routes.cfm) that is nothing more than a simple login form. I run javascript validation on this form (ensuring that username/password fields are filled). But, in my admin page (and user profile page), a user can edit their acct ... that form uses the model validation to ensure user data is correct prior to save().

Comment: The same validation rules should apply just fine to an `update()` scenario though. You load the object, which should contain valid data and then save the newly-changed fields. If you don't believe me, just try it. :)

Comment: Thanks guys...yes, the update form may match every field as the registration has, but there may be additional fields that I didn't require the user to fill in on registration, like a biography or a picture upload. I want them all to use the same model (user.cfc) but I'm not sure what logic I would need in order to split the validation. Maybe I'm just not getting it?? I'm following the screencast tutorials (which are awesome!) but I'm changing up a few things slightly.

Comment: For the extra fields (i.e., extra fields on the update form versus the registration form), what sort of validation do you think you would require? It would seem that the extra update fields would not be required (i.e., they allow nulls in your DB table's columns) and that the necessary validation would be more verifying data type or length or something along those lines. Is that assumption correct?

Comment: I'm sort of stuck on the same problem. I have a a model user.cfc that checks for password length/type and then validates it against "password confirm" but I don't want to force people to always enter their passwords into the edit form. Since they are already logged in. So how do i handle that? I want to have a separate page "Update password" and there again I have to run it through Users.cfc but this time, I don't want the validation on any of the other fields EXCEPT the password fields. What's the bets way to do this? One thing I can think of is a "hidden field" in the form, and then cfif.

Answer (score 0):

Go to this URL and scroll down to: Use "when", "condition", or "unless" to Limit the Scope of Validation
http://cfwheels.org/docs/1-1/chapter/object-validation

For your case, you could probably go with when="onCreate"